# how to show/hide children in an angulartreeview?

Tags: angularjs, treeview, angular-ui

I am looking at the angular treeview (https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview)
How to show/hide the children in the tree?Or do I just need to bind to a different model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like each node can have a boolean property called collapsed that determines whether or not its children are shown.

For example, you can collapse the second child node of the root node like this...

```
treeList[0].children[1].collapsed = false;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/42M8n/) (simplified version of one of their [samples](https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview#examples))